# Problem with ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

i have a strange problem with ParametricNDSolve. Given the sistem of differential euqations

```
fun = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {x'[s] == v[s], v'[s] == a[s], a'[s] == a[s] - 2 x[s] E^(-x[s]^2),
     x[0] == x0, v[0] == v0, a[0] == 0},
    {x, v, a}, {s, tmin, 0}, {x0, v0, tmin}];
```

`ParametricNDSolve` returns the correct solution only for certain values of `tmin`. For example, with

```
{x0, v0} = {10, 2}
```

it gives the correct solution only for `tmin < -74`, while for `tmin > -74` it doesn't.

It's possible to visualize this with

```
Table[Plot[fun[10, 2, -50][[i]][t], {t, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 3}]
Table[Plot[fun[10, 2, -100][[i]][t], {t, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
Plot[fun[10, 2, t][[1]][-5], {t, -100, 0}]
```

where is possible to see the dependence of the solution calculated in `t = -5` on the value of `tmin`. I tried to increase the `WorkingPrecision` but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AccuracyGoal`and `PrecisionGoal`

```
fun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[s] == v[s], v'[s] == a[s], a'[s] == a[s] - 2 x[s] E^(-x[s]^2), 
                   x[0] == x0, v[0] == v0, a[0] == 0}, {x, v, a}, {s, tmin, 0}, {x0, v0, tmin}, 
                                                      AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10];

Table[Plot[fun[10, 2, -50][[i]][t], {t, -10, 0},  PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 3}]
Table[Plot[fun[10, 2, -80][[i]][t], {t, -10, 0},  PlotRange -> All], {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I believe setting `PrecisionGoal` is enough for this problem

Comment: Thanks! i tried that before, but for some reason i thought it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem is with the step size, which is controlled by various options, including `PrecisionGoal` (as shown in [belisarius's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) answer.
It is also controlled by `AccuracyGoal`, `MaxStepSize`, `MaxStepFraction` and some others.

The default setting for `MaxStepFraction` is `1/10`, which is not fine enough to stumble upon a little blip near the initial condition (at the beginning of the integration, which `NDSolve` calculates "backwards" from right to left).  The following shows the step size to be `10`.

```
Clear[fun]; 
fun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   x'[s] == v[s], v'[s] == a[s], a'[s] == a[s] - 2 x[s] E^(-x[s]^2),
   x[0] == x0, v[0] == v0, a[0] == 0},
  {x, v, a}, {s, tmin, 0}, {x0, v0, tmin}];

With[{f0 = fun[10, 2, -100]},
 GraphicsRow@
  Table[Plot[f0[[i]][t], {t, -20, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Mesh -> f0[[i]]["Coordinates"], 
    MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Red}], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Adding any one of the following lines results in an accurate solution for `tmin = -100`.

```
MaxStepSize -> 2         (* should work for all tmin *)
MaxStepFraction -> 1/20  (* relative to the size of tmin *)
AccuracyGoal -> 17, PrecisionGoal -> 0   (* both together *)
PrecisionGoal -> 8.3     (* or higher; > 8.5 is fairly robust *)
```

The problem is undoubtedly that the error estimate near the initial condition is so small that `NDSolve` feels it can take the maximum step.  This passes over the interval of `s` where `x` is small, which is where the acceleration `a[s]` changes significantly.  Another approach is to slow down the integration when `x[s]` gets small.  If `x[s] == 5`, then the term `2 x[s] E^(-x[s]^2)` from `a[s]` will be about `10^-10`, which is perhaps a little small (the default `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` is about `8`). But the starting step size is small enough that the solution is found.

```
Clear[fun];
fun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
   x'[s] == v[s], v'[s] == a[s], a'[s] == a[s] - 2 x[s] E^(-x[s]^2),
   x[0] == x0, v[0] == v0, a[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[x[s] == 5, "RestartIntegration"]},
  {x, v, a}, {s, tmin, 0}, {x0, v0, tmin}];

With[{f0 = fun[10, 2, -100]},
 GraphicsRow@
  Table[Plot[f0[[i]][t], {t, -10, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Mesh -> f0[[i]]["Coordinates"], 
    MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Small], Red}], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This answer basically explains what (I think) is going on with `NDSolve`.  The solution proposed by belisarius seems like a good first stab at solution.  My own knee-jerk reaction in such a case is to try `WorkingPrecision -> 20`, which increases `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` to `10`, as in belisarius's solution, and also uses arbitrary precision reals.  The setting slightly above `MachinePrecision` with the precision tracking gives me some feedback about the numerical stability of the computation of the solution at `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the step size is a function of the domain of the independent variable? I couldn't figure out how changing `tmin` affects the whole integration bacause, as you said, the numerical integration starts at `s=0` and goes backwards.

Comment: @Ivactheseeker Yes, it's a function of the domain among other things.  `NDSolve` tests a few values at the start of the integration interval and adjusts the step size according to its error estimate. In this case, it jumps to `MaxStepFraction`. For `tmin = -50`, it tries the step `-5`; but that lands where `a'[s]` is changing, and the error estimate is too large. So it tries a step of `-5/4 = -1.25`, which it uses until it needs to adjust the step size again.  With `tmin = -100`, the step of `-10` jumps over the variation and the error is estimated to be small; so it keeps on going.

Comment: @Michael_E2 Ok, thanks again!.